# How can I send WM_DROPFILES from C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, drag-and-drop, windows-messages

I want to use C# code to simulate a user dragging and dropping a file onto a control in a separate process.  As a stepping stone to this goal, I am trying to send a WM_DROPFILES message to my own TextBox and verifying that the DragDrop event is triggered.

With the code below in a Form containing a single TextBox and two Buttons, clicking on button1 successfully sets the text of textBox1 to "Hello world".  So, it seems that I'm using SendMessage correctly and am able to supply arguments via pointers.  Dragging and dropping a file from Windows Explorer onto textBox1 displays the MessageBox, so textBox1 is set up to receive drag-dropped files correctly.  However, when I click button2, nothing happens.  Why don't I see a MessageBox when I click button2?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class BadDragDrop : Form
    {
        #region WINAPI

        [Serializable]
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct POINT
        {
            public Int32 X;
            public Int32 Y;
        }

        [Serializable]
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        class DROPFILES
        {
            public Int32 size;
            public POINT pt;
            public Int32 fND;
            public Int32 WIDE;
        }

        const uint WM_DROPFILES = 0x0233;
        const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GlobalLock(IntPtr Handle);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GlobalUnlock(IntPtr Handle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        #endregion

        public BadDragDrop()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string textToSet = "Hello world\0";
            IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(textToSet.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(textToSet.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray(), 0, p, textToSet.Length);
            int success = GlobalUnlock(p);
            SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, p);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Windows\win.ini" + "\0\0";

            DROPFILES s = new DROPFILES()
            {
                size = Marshal.SizeOf<DROPFILES>(),
                pt = new POINT() { X = 10, Y = 10 },
                fND = 0,
                WIDE = 0,
            };

            int wparamLen = s.size + filePath.Length;

            IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(wparamLen);
            int iSuccess = GlobalLock(p);

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(s, p, false);
            Marshal.Copy(filePath.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray(), 0, p + s.size, filePath.Length);

            iSuccess = GlobalUnlock(p);

            var verify = new byte[wparamLen];
            Marshal.Copy(p, verify, 0, wparamLen);

            var ipSuccess = SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, WM_DROPFILES, p, IntPtr.Zero);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        }

        private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Drag drop!");
        }

        private void textBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't see your `MessageBox` appear is likely because the `TextBox` doesn't handle `WM_DROPFILES` messages to begin with.  It implements its drop support using OLE Drag&Drop instead by implementing the [`IDropTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679.aspx) interface (see [Drag and Drop Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview) in the WPF documentation).

`WM_DROPFILES` has been deprecated ever since [`DoDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486.aspx) was introduced way back in Windows 95.  OLE Drag&Drop has been the *preferred* way to implement drag&drop on Windows for a very long time.  `WM_DROPFILES` is still supported by Windows (but not .NET) but only for backwards compatibility with legacy apps.

Dragging items from Windows Explorer to other apps uses OLE Drag&Drop under the hood, even if the receiver doesn't implement OLE Drag&Drop.

If you drag&drop an `IDataObject` onto a window that has had [`RegisterDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405.aspx) called on it (like your `TextBox` has), the `IDataObject` will be passed to the window's `IDropTarget` interface for handling.

If you drag&drop an `IDataObject` onto a window that doesn't implement `IDropTarget`, but has had [`DragAcceptFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776406.aspx) called on it, or at least has the `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` window style, Windows will generate a `WM_DROPFILES` message if the `IDataObject` contains `CF_HDROP` data in it.

So, to do what you are attempting with your `TextBox`, you need to implement the [`IDropSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690071.aspx) and [`IDataObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688421.aspx) interfaces, and then call [`DoDragDrop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486.aspx) with them.  Let Windows handle the actual dragging and dropping for you.  See [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx) and [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx).

Now, with that said, if you are still determined to send a `WM_DROPFILES` message to another process (which your question says is your ultimate goal), you can do that, and Windows will marshal your `DROPFILES` struct across process boundaries for you, but you need to use `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()` (not sure why, only that it is required), and be sure to free the `DROPFILES` only if `PostMessage()` fails.  Windows will free the `DROPFILES` for you if `PostMessage()` is successful.

But even then, there is no guarantee that the receiving process actually handles `WM_DROPFILES` messages (and even if it does, your manual `WM_DROPFILES` message might get blocked by UIPI, unless the receiver calls [`ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675.aspx) on itself to allow `WM_DROPFILES` and `WM_COPYGLOBALDATA` messages).  The receiver might be expecting `IDataObject` instead.  If the receiver even supports drag&drop at all.